# Access repository from entity class

Tags: symfony, repository, entity

I have the following code:

```
    /**
 * Callback transform array of checkboxes to string and store it in database
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function onPreUpdate()
{
    if($this->id == 13)
    {
        $data = implode('-', $this->value);
        $this->setValue($data);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback retrieved data from database transform to string to fill our field
 *
 * @ORM\PostLoad()
 */
public function onPostLoad()
{
    if($this->id == 13)
    {
        $data = (strstr($this->value, '-') !== false) ? explode('-', $this->value) : array($this->value);
        $this->setValue($data);
    }
}
```

I have to do it to transform array of checkboxes in string when I add/update data and vice versa when i retrieve data from database to put them in checkbox widget.
But now is static that is by id, I need to check my input type and if it is an checkbox run the code above...
I can't do it:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository();
```

In my entity class because it's doesn't work and it's not good idea for data mapper...so how can i do it?

Thanks for all reply and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

That is not good way of programming 
if you want to transform data while persisting before or after database then you can use  symfony2 doctrine [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: nvm!
now i know how to do it!I don't know about retrieve data from another proporerty when it has a relationship with other entity class so i can access in my entity doing it:
`$options->getWidget()`